# Same error even after updating ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I attempted to update my ChromeDriver from the version that supports Chrome 114 to the most recent (for Chrome version 119) but when I try to use Selenium via VBA I get the error message "Run-time error '33': SessionNotCreatedError session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current broswer version is 119.0.6045.124...."

But have I not updated ChromeDriver?!?

```
Private cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub FindingElements()

Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim query As String
Dim search_string As String

cd.Start

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Why would I be getting this error?

Comment: How are you initializing the driver? If you are specifying a path, have you installed it from [here](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)?

Comment: You need to show your codes.

Comment: apologies. code now added